# Display error if empty field - PHP

Tags: php, forms, validation, submit

I want to display an error on the same page if any field is empty.

I've got this, which works but the empty error is displayed as soon as the page is loaded instead of appearing once empty fields are submitted.

```
<?php
    // Required field names
    $required = array('triangleSide1', 'triangleSide2', 'triangleSide3');

    // Loop over field names, make sure each one exists and is not empty
    $error = false;
    foreach($required as $field) 
    {
        if (empty($_POST[$field])) 
        {
            $error = true;
        }
    }

    if ($error) 
    {
        echo "ALL FIELDS ARE REQUIRED";
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo header('Location: formSuccess.php');
    }
?>
```

Any ideas? -- UPDATE // IVE TRIED ALL ANSWERS, nothing has worked so far

Comment: then you need javascript validation. Also adding 'required="required"' to text fields works in the modern browsers (http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-form-validation/)

Comment: Just change the if ($error) to if ($error = true), the if statement doesn't know what to do with $error and is probably just checking if it exists

Comment: adding the =true doesnt change anything sadly

Comment: `=` is an assignment operator, not a comparison operator changing to `if($error = true)` won't work (or at least not in the way you think it will) ... `if($error == true)` would but that's exactly the same as `if($error)` in PHP-land so changing it to that is pointless : there's nothing wrong with just `if($error)` as long as you're not strictly evaluating type.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap everything you check on post in this:

```
if (strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) == 'post')
{
    // Your code containing checks here
}
```

This way, it will only trigger when a POST request is used.

Comment: What do you mean, same result? If you wrap your code in this, it will only trigger on a post request, so that must mean you're already reaching the page via post. In that case, you'll have to add additional checks. Which version of PHP are you using? `empty` behaves differently in various versions of PHP. Also, for checkboxes, you will have to check with `isset()` if the key is set, since they will not appear if not checked.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an input you know will always be submitted with the form, such as a hidden one:

```
<input type='hidden' name='formsubmit' value='1'>
```

Then you can test for this before validating the other inputs

```
if($_POST["formsubmit"]) {
   // Required field names
    $required = array('triangleSide1', 'triangleSide2', 'triangleSide3');

    // Loop over field names, make sure each one exists and is not empty
    $error = false;
    foreach($required as $field) {
      if (empty($_POST[$field])) {
          $error = true;
        }
    }

    if ($error) {
        echo "ALL FIELDS ARE REQUIRED";
    } else {
        header('Location: formSuccess.php');
    }
}
```

Also you don't echo the return of header()

Comment: dont quite understand what im doing with the input type hidden line?

Comment: If you don't already have an input that is guaranteed to be set, then you can add that hidden input to your form, so that no matter what the user inputs, that hidden value will always been sent, providing a reliable way of knowing when the form was submit

Answer (score 0):

```
OR another way ( I have something similar in one of my pages)
 function check_presence($value){
   return isset($value) && $value!=="";
 }
 function validate($required){
   global $error
   foreach($required as $field){
      $value = trim($_POST[$field]);
      if (!check_presence($value)){
          $error = true;          
      }
   }
   return $error;
}
then on the page containing the form and its validation code
$required = array('triangleSide1',  'triangleSide2', 'triangleSide3');
if(isset($_POST["submit"]){
   $error = validate($required);
   if ($error){
      echo "ALL FIELDS ARE REQUIRED";
   }
}
```

Comment: Really? That's just wrong ... you're setting `$check` and than checking to see if it's **not** set? I think this might be **more** wrong than the previous answer I had to downvote... what the OP has in the question `if(empty($_POST[$field]))` is exactly correct.

Comment: And be sure that this validation code is wraped in a condition i.e. say in a if statement and will be executed only when the 'submit' value is set in the $_POST super global i.e. to say that the form has been submited

Comment: checking isset for $check will ensure that none of the required fields are left blank or unset. You are reading from an array of required fields which may have blank values.

Comment: `$check = null;` ... `isset($check) === true` ... `empty($check) === true` ... your conditional `$check = trim($_POST[$field])` will 1: assign `$check = null` and 2: throw a PHP "undefined index" notice. That being the case this condition `if (!isset($check)` will never happen as `isset($check)` will never evaluate to `false`

Comment: ...actually `trim()` will cast it to a string so `$check = trim($_POST[$field])` when the form hasn't been posted will assign `$check = ""` - either way, it's still defined.

Comment: ... better; you don't need that first code block any more, the second is actually right(ish).

Comment: You've still got flaws and `isset($value)` in the function can never evaluate to false ... but the logic at least makes a bit more sense now, removed the downvote.

Answer (score -1):

Try isset instest of empty!!!

```
if (empty($_POST[$field]))
```

Become

```
if (isset($_POST[$field]))
```

Comment: That's actually going to make matters worse - `empty()` checks to see if a variable is set **and** has a true-ish value, `isset()` merely checks that a variable is set ... and by not negating `isset()` here you're going to trigger the error whenever `$_POST[$field]` **is set** (rather than when **not** set) irrespective as to whether it holds any data or not.